# Viewing Rails Credentials in WSL2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wsl-2

I'm following a guide which uses rails credentials but I can't edit the unencrypted file.

I first run `EDITOR="code --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit --environment=development` which creates `development.key` & `development.yml.enc`. However it fails to open up the unencrypted version of the file it showed in the guide.

I have tried `EDITOR="code --wait" bin/rails credentials:show --environment=development` which shows the file in the terminal with the expected AWS placeholder key and secret. It also provides a number of warnings. But I can't edit.

Are there any other methods to access Rails' unencrypted credentials from a WSL2 environment? I am presuming WSL2 is the cause of the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using NANO editor instead seems to work.

`EDITOR="nano" bin/rails credentials:edit --environment=development`

I'll leave the question up for anyone else with this issue.

Comment: Thanks Christian! This solved the same issue I was having.